# Importing everything from parent folder as a module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, directory, python-import

My project is structured like this right now:

```
Game
|__init__.py
|Breakout.py
|Ball.py
|Pad.py
|Shared -
        |__init__.py
        |GameConstants.py
```

The __init__.py file in the Game folder has the following text:

```
from Game.Ball import Ball
from Game.Pad import Pad
```

What I am trying to do, is importing this parent module in the `Breakout` class. Doing something like this works in the PyCharm IDE:

```
from Game import *
```

But it does not work in another IDE, like Visual Studio Code.

Is there an easy solution to do this?
(Running python 3.6)

Comment: Well starting the python file without the IDE right now just gives me a "ModuleNotFoundErrror: No module named 'game'", but i do not know how to fix this, in Visual Studio Code, for example.

Comment: Well, is the module on your PYTHONPATH / `sys.path`?

Comment: I have tried running something like:
sys.path.insert(0, r"R:\My\Project\path\Game")

Comment: Well, that's the wrong path. Try again without the `\Game` part.

Comment: Wow, that actually just did it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sys module to add the directory 'one up' to your path. Then you can access the files in your current directory.

__init__.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
from Game.Ball import Ball
from Game.Pad import Pad
```